# What does aspectj-weaver.jar do?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, aspectj

What does aspectj-weaver.jar do? What are its common uses?

Comment: I'd like to point out that the only thing wrong with this post is bad English/grammar skills. Its brevity does not preclude it from the scope of SO. *scowls at the close votes*

Comment: I concur -- sad to see word count used a proxy for question quality

Comment: I also concur. This is a most excellent question.

It is perfectly obvious what is being asked here. It is completely unambiguous, not at all vague, 100% complete, precisely limited in scope, not rhetorical, and can very definitely be answered in its current form.

This behavior is completely antithetical to what SO is all about.

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The jar is used in aspectj for aspect oriented programming or AOP.

The weaver is the piece that actually "weaves" together the aspects/point-cuts/join-points defined with the code that is to be executed in each instance.

Answer (score 11):

The answers here are not really clear (even though schnaader's link to a README points to the right info), so I am going to add a more precise one:

*aspectjweaver.jar* is an **AspectJ** library needed for **LTW (load-time weaving)**, as opposed to compile-time weaving.

Answer (score 2):

This is from [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) - also see [this](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-121.html).

Comment: The AspectJ 1.2.1 distribution contains a new jar in the lib directory, aspectjweaver.jar, that contains the subset of aspectjtools.jar needed for weaving only. This jar may be used in situations where you wish to exploit AspectJ's binary weaving capabilities, but do not want the full aspectjtools.jar around (aspectjweaver.jar is approx. 5 times smaller).